# Can Monolog be used on GAE and have the logging levels recorded in Stack Driver?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-stackdriver, monolog

There are a number of [posts](https://medium.com/@shaharia/php-application-logging-in-google-app-engine-analyze-them-in-smart-way-7ef1e58ed8d7) on the internet that indicate the right way to use Monolog on the google app engine (GAE standard) is like so:

```
   $logger = new  Monolog\Logger($name);
   $syslogHandler = new \Monolog\Handler\SyslogHandler("Ident_String", LOG_USER, \Monolog\Logger::INFO);
        $syslogHandler->setFormatter(new \Monolog\Formatter\JsonFormatter());
        $logger->pushHandler($syslogHandler);
        break;


    $logger->warn("Starting priam import." );
```

That does get me logging, but the level is buried in the textPayload:

> textPayload: "[28-Feb-2020 11:00:07] WARNING: [pool app] child 22
>   said into stderr: "[2020-02-28 06:00:07] match_old.INFO: Doing a super
>   huge SELECT to get all intls. [] []""

and the level icon is always a stippled out asterisk. 
[image]
Has something changed? I'm using the php 7.3 run-time on GAE standard.  Is there a way to use Monolog on GAE that let's you take proper use of stack driver?

Comment: Have you tried changing `\Monolog\Logger::INFO)` to `\Monolog\Logger::DEBUG)`? Also how are you specifically logging whatever you need from within your application) Using `$logger->info("whatever needs to be logged");` or any other approach?

Comment: Hello @Robert, did you find a response to your question by any chance ? I currently have the same issue.

Comment: I started swapping Google\Cloud\Logging\LoggingClient where I could. Actually I run monolog locally and google remotely. Really pisses me off!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a package available that allows you  to push Monolog to Stackdriver.

As per the doc:

> The supplied StackdriverHandler copies the given log level into the
>   Stackdriver's severity based on your log method.
>
> It also respects the context argument which allows you to send extra
>   contextual data with your log message. This will be stored in the log
>   message under jsonPayload.data.

The source code can be found here [monolog-stackdriver](https://github.com/codeinternetapplications/monolog-stackdriver)

Comment: You're welcome.. I worked on Google Cloud Platform Support other users found that it worked for them

Answer (score 0):

I wound up conditionally loading a different logger locally than I do on GAE. It's workable, but it seems like an unnecessary hack considering monolog is such a popular library. And, oh, it's 2020.

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Cloud\Logging\LoggingClient;

function  get_logger($name) {
    $kind = getenv('LOG_TYPE')?:'remote';
    return _get_logger($kind, $name);
}

function _get_logger($kind, $name) {
    if ($kind ==='local') {
        $logger = new  Monolog\Logger($name);
        $logger->pushHandler(new Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler('php://stdout', Monolog\Logger::INFO));
        return $logger;
    }
    $logging = new LoggingClient();
    $logger = $logging->psrLogger($name);
    return $logger;
}
```

I'm hoping someone can make this work with monolog.